# PHP special Characters

Tags: php, mysql

When i enter data from a form into a sql database the code below sometimes still doesn't insiert special characters correctly.

```
$titel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titel']);
```

I have no clue what it can be....

An example

```
Assassinâ€™s Creed Unity â€“
```

The same character sometimes does work...

```
Destiny's Raids
```

Some more examples....

```
Hyrule Warriors â€˜Ciaâ€™ gameplay<br>
Dragon Age: Inquisition Gameplay Features â€“ Crafting &am<br>
NBA 2K15 â€“ Welcome To MyPARK<br>
Sid Meierâ€™s Civilization: Beyond Earth â€&ldq
```

Any tips?

Comment: did you try to SET NAMES as UTF-8

Comment: In general you should think about moving to the more modern database adapters like mysqli or PDO which do such escaping internally and much more reliable than the old fashioned approach base on such manual escaping functions. Start reading about "prepared statements"!

Comment: You seem to be inserting/getting info in UTF-8, but displaying in ISO-8859-1. And what @arkascha said: use prepared statements. Make sure all parts of your system use UTF-8 and you should be fine.

Comment: Please don't write new code using the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do this guidelines for a working UTF8 solution:

1. Use SET NAMES 'utf-8' when opening your database connection, for example:

```
$bd = mysql_connect(BD_SERVER, BD_USER, BD_PASSWORD);

mysql_select_db(BD_DATABASE, $bd);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $bd);
```

2. Use utf8_general_ci AS your database collation.
3. Save your PHP files with UTF-8 encoding.
4. Put in headers of your pages next meta: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`